# Difference between MVC4 and MVC4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I got this question triggered in interview. Is there any difference between MVC4 and MVC4 Web API?

I just responded with API returns some `JSON` or `XML` result. Is there anything more than this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In WebApi is likely to be a subset of full MVC.

- It does not contains views.
- The controller is different. In WebApi it is `ApiController` instead of `Controller`.  Major difference is that actions on Web API controllers do not return views, they return data.

In my opinion you should do some [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api) and see difference by yourself

Comment: +1, Thanks for the definition.